# Indented while loop not executing- python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a while loop under another while loop and the inner loop is not being executed

code:

```
def iterate():
    while True:
        print 'jk jk'   
        while freqsenderdict.i in freqsenderdict.senders:
            print 'In here'
            #some function calls
    return
```

It only prints

> jk jk

freqsenderdict is another module imported in this program.
code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
i = 0
senders = {
        1 : 600,
        2 : 601
        }
```

If I don't declare `i` in `freqsenderdict`, I get the error: global name i is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, based on your explanation,

```
i = 0
senders = {
        1 : 600,
        2 : 601
        }
```

`freqsenderdict.i` is not in `freqsenderdict.senders`. be cool

Comment: Oh ok, so how do I iterate through this dictionary in another module?

Comment: Why do you want to iterate over a dict BTW?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf because in the original code, both keys and the values are something important and I want to access them both.

Comment: In that case, you could use `for key, value in freqsenderdict.senders.items():`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the inner while loop not satisfies the condition.
ie, `freqsenderdict.i in freqsenderdict.senders:` (False). 
You have to use while loop carefully. Based of your code if the condition satisfies the loop will run infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

For the future readers:

I wrote this code wrong. It should have been `for` instead of `while` and that made it work.